# View borderRadius style not applied on Android when view is inside a FlatList

Tags: android, css, react-native, styling, react-native-flatlist

I have a component that I used for selecting dates in a calendar. If a date is selected, the number should have circle as a background. I have wrapped the `<Text>` in a `<View>` with a `borderRadius` styling and the component itself works.

But when I render my component in a `<FlatList>`, the `borderRadius` is simply not applied on Android.

Check out the screenshots for iOS and Android.

I've tried a lot of adjustments but with no luck, and now reach out. An Expo example of my component code is here, the component itself is `DaySelectorItem.js`, and the list is in `DaySelectorItem.js`

Code here https://snack.expo.io/@esbenvb/android-square-circles

Thank you in advance :)

[image: android shows squares]

[image: iOS works as expected]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i usually group the border props together, so i got it working on both platforms by moving the `borderRadius` value from dayWrapper to SelectedDayWrapper. hope this helps!

```
  selectedDayWrapper: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    borderColor: 'pink',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: CIRCLE_1_SIZE,
  },
  dayWrapper: {
    width: CIRCLE_1_SIZE,
    height: CIRCLE_1_SIZE,
    // borderRadius: CIRCLE_1_SIZE,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  },
```

Comment: Thank you! I also tried adding the pure `DaySelectorItem` component without the flatlist, and update `isSelected` prop using component state. Same result.

It seems like Android "forgets" the borderRadius if not immediately relevant (no border or background), so it's unavailable when a style is applied, that makes use of the borderRadius.